# get matching substrings from long string Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this

```
   jasabcasjlabcdjjakabcdehahakabcdef...//any number of characters
```

I want regex that returns these substrings

```
  [abc],[abcd],[abcde],[abcdef],....
```

I have written regex something like this

```
 @"abc(?=[d-z])+
```

But it's not bringing what I want, I have been trying for some time, please help

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `abc[d-z]*`? otherwise please clear the rules.

Comment: @revo no check the sample result 'abc,abcd,abcde...' means it starts searching abc then abcd then abcde...and so on

Comment: Regular Expressions match on some defined rules. What rules do you have?

Comment: @revo rule:start with `abc` then search for next set of characters that it one length longer and in sequence and keep going until end of string

Comment: so basically `abc(d(e(f(...))?)?)?` ?

Comment: @Lanorkin can't there be a pattern I can use instead of specify all characters in regex

Comment: @Alex No, there is not.

Comment: @Alex not sure that a regex is a good tool for exactly this task; just scan string for first `a`, then starting from that match increment char to look for until still matches, when not matched - stop, flush and start again. O(N) and simple to understand. Other than that - just type all the letters yourself once :)

Comment: ok thanks all. good to know

Comment: What @Lanorkin suggests doesn't tell engine to match a character longer in length in the next iteration. It basically depends on your input string to be ordered the same way it is. Simply these rules couldn't be written in an expression. It's a job for a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq approach

```
string input = "jasabcasjlabcdjjakabcdehahakabcdef";
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"(?=abc)")
                       .Select(x => string.Concat(x.TakeWhile((y, i) => y == ('a' + i))))
                       .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                       .ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tahJ4U

Answer (score 1):

Approach with a `foreach`-loop

```
string input = "jasabcasjlabcdjjakabcdehahakabcdef";

List<string> result = new List<string>();
string temp = string.Empty;

foreach(char c in input)
{
    if(c == 'a' && temp == string.Empty)
    {
        temp = string.Empty;
        temp += c;                
    }
    else if(c - 1  == temp.LastOrDefault())
    {
        temp += c;                  
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
    {
        if (temp.StartsWith("abc"))
        {
            result.Add(temp);
        }
        temp = string.Empty;
    }
}
if (temp.StartsWith("abc"))
{
    result.Add(temp);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4t9Cq